# How to detect user has tapped "Use Photo" button in the camera?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

When user takes a photo via devices camera, the photo appears with two button underneath itself - **Retake** & **Use Photo**. Is there any way to detect whether user has tapped the **Use Photo** button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after user clicks "Use Photo" delegate method `didfinishPickingMediawithInfo` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the delegate UIImagePickerControllerDelegate take a look at the official documentation of apple

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate

Implement the

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

in the ViewController which calls the UIImagePickerController and set the delegate to the calling ViewController.